# DLookup not working when using a variable?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've got some code that runs on form load:

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()
'Declare the username variable
 Dim loginID As String
'Get the username from the environment array variable
 loginID = Environ("USERNAME")
'Pop up a message box stating the obvious and checking the variable is set
 MsgBox ("Hello " & loginID")
'Lookup the permissions of the user based on the windows logon
 MsgBox DLookup("permissions", "Users", "userName = " & loginID)
```

When I run this code, the "test" message box works and it pops up my windows login id, but when the code continues and I get to the DLookup, I get a VBA error:

2471 The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error:
'MORINDAV'

If I change the Dlookup statement to this:

```
MsgBox DLookup("permissions", "Users", "userName = 'loginID'")
```

I get error '94', invalid use of Null.

If I keep the same syntax as above, but manually enter the user value I'm testing for like this:

```
MsgBox DLookup("permissions", "Users", "userName = 'MORINDAV'")
```

The statement works and VBA shows me a message box with that user's permissions level.

I'm sure it's a syntax issue but I can't seem to get the DLookup to work while using the variable: loginID

Comment: Beware `Environ("USERNAME")` can be easily defeated by opening a Windows command prompt, setting USERNAME to a bogus value, and then starting Access from within that session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`userName` and `loginID` are text type, so enclose the value of `loginID` in quotes.

```vb
DLookup("permissions", "Users", "userName = '" & loginID & "'")
```

Comment: This totally worked, just to clarify for future, if the variable is a number, the way I had it before would work?

Comment: Right, you wouldn't quote a number.  If it was Date/Time, you would add `#` delimiters like ... `#2014-03-19#`